# New line in constant error from c#

Tags: c#

This line occur new line in constant error..how can i fix this?

```
Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
```

Comment: Don't write your code in your title.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: can you provide code related to the initialization of Latitude, Longitute and Locations variables?

Comment: @daryal `code`DemoDBDataContext db = new DemoDBDataContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Locations = "";
            foreach (var position in db.Locations)
            {
                string lastlat = position.Latitude.ToString();
                string lastlng = position.Longtitude.ToString();

                Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay
          (new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `"\"` string directly in C# code, it produces "new line in constant" error. One of your variables is equal to `"\"`, I can not directly say since the code section you have provided does not include the related initialization code.

instead of using `"\"`, just escape the slash character using `"\\"`.

Comment: can you help me to do correction?